# Kivy: settings button on android

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'm building my first android app using kivy, and I got to a minor issue with the settings I just want to be sure about.

while running the app on PC I'm able to reach the settings panel using "F1", without placing a dedicated "settings button" in my app. How can I do the same in android (means, without calling *app.open_settings* menually?)

I found this on kivy docs (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html):

> That’s all! Now you can press F1 (default keystroke) to toggle the settings panel or press the “settings” key on your android device.

so it seems there is a way to do that, I just can't find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Kivy source code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/37292f00a8a457762a94011d7719e2c7d03d821c/kivy/app.py#L1175), we can see that it binds the settings key to 'K_MENU' on android if SDL2 is not used. This is (I'm assuming, as there is very little information on this) the android menu button, which isn't on any new android phones and [was retired in Android 10](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/11/13/the-menu-navigation-button-has-finally-been-retired-in-android-10/).

```
def _on_keyboard_settings(self, window, *largs):
...
# android hack, if settings key is pygame K_MENU
        if platform == 'android' and not USE_SDL2:
            import pygame
            setting_key = pygame.K_MENU
```

This code is 11 years old, so it was written when menu buttons were common on Android phones. You will probably just have to implement a dedicated settings button, such as in a menu bar.